# WPF basic binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know this has been asked quite a few times, but no matter how many tutorials I read, I simply cannot understand it. I have a grid with three ColumnDefinitions that can be resized via two GridSplitters. What I want is another grid below it with three ColumnDefinitions that resize as the top grid is being resized (much alike the UI in a program like iTunes). The reason I want separate grids is because eventually, each grid will be its own object and will need drag and drop properties. Here is the Xaml I have written if anyone wants to see what I'm looking at.

```
<Canvas Width="400" Height="15" Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400" Name='Maingrid'>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="140" MinWidth="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="116" MinWidth="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="144" MinWidth="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Black" 
          ShowsPreview="True"
          Width="2"
          />
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Black" 
          ShowsPreview="True"
          Width="2"
          />
            <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="1" Width="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="2" Width="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Width="400" Height="15" Background="RosyBrown" Margin="58,168,59,138">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="140" MinWidth="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="116" MinWidth="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="144" MinWidth="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="1" Width="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="2" Width="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

Also as a final note, I've looked at endless amounts of tutorials and guides on data binding and my 17 year old brain just can't seem to wrap my head around it. If I could understand how to make a textblock be bound to a variable in my C# codebehind (aka: not setting the textblock's text property in the codebehind, but simply changing the contents of a string), I'd be able to be so much more productive. Thank you to anyone who can help me, I know this question has been asked a million times.

Comment: You are asking two questions here, @hosch250 has answered the first, whilst I have (perhaps badly) answered the second

Comment: Don't worry, it took me days (over a week?) to understand data binding, but when I understood it, it just came really fast.  Once you understand one-way binding, play around with two-way binding for a while, learn converters, and you will be good.

Answer (score 1):

In your c# codebehind, create a property:

```
private string _songTitle;
public string SongTitle { get { return _songTitle; } set { songTitle = value; } }
```

In your xaml, create a binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SongTitle}" />
```

Set the DataContext for your binding (you could put this in the `Window.Loaded` event)

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Set your property in your code

```
SongTitle = "Some words and stuff";
```

That's about it. It can get more complicated, but that's the basics.

Comment: NotifyPropertyChange should be implemented if he wants changes to be reflected in the UI.

Comment: Yes, was trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it without code behind.  Just give your first column definitions names, then bind the lower column definitions widths' to the width of the appropriate column definitions in the first grid.  Clean and simple, no code behind to mess with:

```
<Canvas Width="400" Height="15" Background="AntiqueWhite">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400" Name='Maingrid'>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="Grid1Col1" Width="140" MinWidth="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="Grid1Col2" Width="116" MinWidth="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="Grid1Col3" Width="144" MinWidth="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0"
      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Background="Black" 
      ShowsPreview="True"
      Width="2"
      />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Background="Black" 
      ShowsPreview="True"
      Width="2"
      />
        <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="1" Width="30"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="2" Width="30"/>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>

<Canvas Width="400" Height="15" Background="RosyBrown" Margin="58,168,59,138">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Grid1Col1}" MinWidth="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Grid1Col1}" MinWidth="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Grid1Col1}" MinWidth="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="1" Width="30"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Song" Grid.Column="2" Width="30"/>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```